# How to approximate mixed derivative with respect to all variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I want to compute or approximate  $$ \frac{\partial^n f(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_0 \dots \partial x_n}$$ in pretty high dimensional problem.

Modern autodiff engines (like the one in `pytorch`) can derive computational scheme for something like a gradient or even a Hessian, but I have no idea how one could get or approximate a mixed derivative like this for a complicated function $f$. Taking partial derivative one hundred times in a loop does not sound practical. Any ideas? Any way to get something similar, but simpler?

Comment: What is the explicit form of $f(x)$?

Comment: @AlexR. it is a \*cough\* neural network, hope it does not show me in a bad light :) so it is a long composition of matrix multiplications, and nonlinear functions like logistic function; maybe there is a more proper way of calling this rather then "mixed derivative with respect to all variables", I am not aware of, so I could google it?

Comment: Why do you need such a mixed derivative approximation for a neural network, out of curiosity? Also even if it's a neural network, the activations should be easy to differentiate an arbitrary number of times by hand

Comment: @AlexR. I am trying to approximate high dimensional cdf by a neural network by adding couple of tricks to ensure that it is actually cdf, it would be nice to be able to compute pdf at a given point from approximated cdf; if f is cdf then the mixed derivative above is exactly the value of pdf; I initially thought pdf might be similar to a norm of a gradient of f, but it seems like that is not the case

Comment: Sure. You know the structure of your neural network along with all the weights, so again, I'm confused why you can't explicitly calculate the derivatives, even if it requires using autodiff. Once you have the calculating, you've solved the problem for all $x$.